# Get name and dimensions of all images in a folder

Tags: python, image, batch-file

How do I get names and dimensions of all images in a folder? I have over 50k images in a folder. I need list of names along with dimensions of all image files. Windows 7 PC with Mediainfo and Python installed. Can install other software if needed like ImageMagick.

---

**Edited by Mofi to show Renuka how to ask right.**

I have in folder `C:\Temp\My Pictures` and its subfolders over 50.000 image files with names like

- **Subfolder 1**

  - My Photo1.jpg
- **OneMoreSubFolder**

  - Another Photo.jpg
- PNG image.png

The file extensions to support are: JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP

In want to get the name of each image file with path into a CSV file `C:\Temp\ImageList.csv` with:

1. file name with path in double quotes
2. width of image in pixels
3. height of image in pixels

The separator should be a comma, i.e. `,`

The CSV file should look for example for above file list:

```
"C:\Temp\My Pictures\Subfolder 1\My Photo1.jpg",800,600
"C:\Temp\My Pictures\OneMoreSubFolder\Another Photo.jpg",768,1024
"C:\Temp\My Pictures\PNG image.png",48,36
```

The code I have so far is:

```
rem Here should be your code. You should have already searched in WWW
rem by yourself how to fulfill this task and tried something by yourself.
```

My problem is that ...

How to ...?

*Such a question would be welcome on Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ImageMagick and run

```
identify -format "%f,%w,%h\n" *.jpg > filelist.csv
```

**Sample Output**

```
identify -format "%f,%w,%h\n" *.jpg *.png

a.jpg,870,946
b.jpg,298,219
bd.jpg,3138,1877
bean1.jpg,1252,1252
bean2.jpg,500,355
bh.jpg,1877,3138
book.jpg,1715,3049
cap.jpg,300,221
fg.jpg,180,252
fractal.jpg,38400,21600
result.jpg,100,100
score.jpg,870,946
1.png,400,300
1b.png,202,102
2.png,400,300
2b.png,202,102
3.png,103,115
3b.png,202,102
```

or

```
identify -format "%f, width=%w, height=%h\n" *.jpg
```

If you want to do the same for `PNG` or `TIF` files, just change the `jpg` to `png` or `tif`.

Comment: This displayed 

    dogsandcats.jpg JPEG 958x1644 958x1644+0+0 8-bit sRGB 254KB  0.000u 0:00.000

any way to only diplay width and height seperately ? also can it create a csv file ?

Comment: Sorry i meant name width height . I tried it it joins width and height . Any way to add a space between them ?

Comment: Try `identify -format "%f,%w,%h\n" *.jpg > filelist.csv`

Comment: Worked perfectly . One last request , any way to display like this file name width=value height=value ? Also what modifications for other formats ?

Comment: In general, please edit your original question if you're expanding its scope.
In this case, you can change `*.jpg` to any format you like, e.g. `*.gif`. You could use a batch file to easily format your CSV however you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see dimensions and do not want to have a document containing everything (after any programming part involved) then you don't even need a software at all. It's a builtin feature in Windows. Just go to the folder and switch the view to `Detail` mode and right click the title on the top. Choose `more` and from the list of columns, choose `Dimensions`. Confirm the dialog box and you're back to the folder. Now you can see the dimensions of all of the images in that folder.

Comment: I want the details in list format in a text file or csv file.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use free (for private usage) [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) and use the command line:

```
"Path to IrfanView\i_view32.exe "Path to folder with images\*.*" "/info=Path to list file\ImageInfo.lst"
```

The output in the list file for 1 JPEG file is for example:

```
[photo.jpg]
File name = photo.jpg
Directory = 
Compression = JPEG, quality: 92, subsampling ON (2x1)
Resolution = 180 x 180 DPI
Image dimensions = 1024 x 768  Pixels (4:3)
Print size = 14.4 x 10.8 cm; 5.69 x 4.27 inches
Color depth = 16,7 Million   (24 BitsPerPixel)
Number of unique colors = 53939
Disk size = 225.87 KB (231.293 Bytes)
Current memory size = 2.25  MB (2.359.336 Bytes)
File date/time = 19.05.2014 / 15:14:32
```

Comment: This displays all the details . I want only name and dimensions .

Comment: Yes, but with a few simple batch commands you can extract just file name and image dimensions to one more text file, for example with `findstr`. But as you can read at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the Stack Overflow community is not for doing the entire work for you which is the reason why your question has already got 2 down votes in 15 minutes and will be closed most likely in a few hours or days.

Comment: Ya I know . You guys are intelligent .But this place isn't noob friendly. Most people hate this place . Everybody isn't a nerd like you guys . Also there is no way to know why the question was downvoted . I have been downvoted many times but I don't know why . How can I improve next time if I don't know the reason .